# issues with adding childnode to subnode in tree extjs4

Tags: extjs4

I am trying to add one child node dynamically to a subnode. but it is not showing in tree.
when i am debugging, i can see it added to currNode.

```
    currNode = Ext.getCmp('TreePanel').getRootNode().childNodes[indexval];
    currNode.appendChild({
        text: text,
        title: 12,
        leaf: true
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by using expand method

```
currentNode.expand();
```

i tried setting properties like child node false, expandable true etc,but calling explicit method made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You must add child node to nodes which are parent node (i.e having children nodes). Adding to leaf node will be ineffective.